TensorFlow and Quadratic Functions
I was trying to get Tensorflow to model/predict y=x^2.  After reading around, I gathered that using the tanh activation helps capture non-linearities.  However, all I am getting are straight-line predictions no matter what I try.  It is typically offset from the curve it should match, as well.
Please see the plot below for an example. Cyan is the original data (y=x^2), blue dashed is the test portion, while the rest of the cyan is training data.  Solid, blue straight line is the output of model.predict

Any idea how I can better model and match non-linear data such as this?
Here is my code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matlab.engine
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

# Parameters
myX = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
myY = np.zeros(len(myX))
for ii, x in enumerate(myX):
    myY[ii] = myX[ii] ** 2

myY_flattened = myY.flatten()
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'myX': myX,
    'myY': myY
})
print(data.head())

plt.plot(myX, myY)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('y=x^2')
plt.show()


# Normalize the features
scaler_inputs = MinMaxScaler()
myX_scaled = scaler_inputs.fit_transform(data['myX'].values.reshape(-1, 1))

scaler_outputs = MinMaxScaler()
myY_scaled = scaler_outputs.fit_transform(data['myY'].values.reshape(-1, 1))

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(myX_scaled, myY_scaled, test_size=0.2,
                                                    shuffle=False)

# Print the shapes to verify
print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)
print('*' * 50)

model = Sequential([
    Dense(128, input_dim=1, activation='tanh'),
    Dense(64, activation='tanh'),
    Dense(32, activation='tanh'),
    Dense(1)
])

optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)  # Decrease the learning rate
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=['mse'], metrics=['mse'])

# Define early stopping callback
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=4, restore_best_weights=True)

# Train the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=300, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2,
                    callbacks=[early_stopping])

# Evaluate the model on the test set
test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print(f"Test Loss: {test_loss:.4f}")
print(f"Test Accuracy: {test_accuracy:.4f}")

# Make predictions on the test set
y_pred_scaled = model.predict(X_test)  # Predicted probabilities for each timestep in the sequence

# Reshape X_test back to 2D for inverse_transform
myX_orig = scaler_inputs.inverse_transform(X_test)
myY_orig = scaler_outputs.inverse_transform(y_test)

y_pred = scaler_outputs.inverse_transform(y_pred_scaled)

# Start MATLAB engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()

eng.figure(nargout=0)
eng.plot(myX, myY, 'c', 'Linewidth', 3, nargout=0)
eng.hold('on', nargout=0)
eng.plot(np.array(myX_orig[:, 0]), myY_orig, 'b--', 'Linewidth', 3, nargout=0)
eng.plot(np.array(myX_orig[:, 0]), y_pred, 'b*', 'Linewidth', 3, nargout=0)
eng.title('y=x^2, original and predicted', nargout=0)
eng.xlabel('Samples', nargout=0)
eng.ylabel('Collisions', nargout=0)

eng.figure(nargout=0)
eng.plot(myX_scaled[:,0], myY_scaled, 'c', 'Linewidth', 3, nargout=0)
eng.hold('on', nargout=0)
eng.plot(np.array(X_test[:, 0]), y_test, 'b--', 'Linewidth', 3, nargout=0)
eng.plot(np.array(X_test[:, 0]), y_pred_scaled, 'b*', 'Linewidth', 3, nargout=0)
eng.title('y=x^2, original and predicted', nargout=0)
eng.xlabel('Samples', nargout=0)
eng.ylabel('Collisions', nargout=0)

# Wait for all figures to be closed
eng.wait_for_figures(nargout=0)


(1) remove the EarlyStopping for the first pass. You can add it back later. 1000 samples isn't a lot and the model might need more than a dozen epochs to learn it. (2) only try 1 hidden layer with the the number of nodes being the number of features in your dataset. This isn't a very complex problem, no need for an overly complicated model (3) don't worry about scaling the data right now, not super necessary for this problem

Thanks @m13op22.  Tried all the above, but no joy.  Still get a straight-line prediction that is not very good

I rebuilt your problem and did a couple of things that worked for me to get to a good prediction 
Those being in summary:

added a dropout and l2 layers to prevent overfitting
included ReduceLROnPlateau to reduce the learning rate if the model plateaus to ensure better convergence
increased early stopping
added the r2 score to see variance in the data
changed your activation function to relu (although tanh is doing fine as well)
switched to StandardScaler because you MinMaxScaler might actually make things worse since your X is growing much faster than your y values
added shuffling to minimize order bias


Thanks for the reply. I got this working yesterday with some help from ChatGPT.  Similar to what you did above.  But, looks like a couple more things I can try from your list.  Your prediction looks a little tighter than mine currently, so we'll see if it helps!
